# How to convert bash to python3?

Tags: python, bash

How to convert this bash script to python3 with standard libs (not to add paramiko etc):

```
   for ((i=1; i<50; i++)); do ssh BF-c${i}nl 'hostname; free -h; uname -a;';
```

Comment: use `range`, `os.uname` and `subprocess`, everything you need to know can be found in docs.python.org. Good luck and update your question when you're stuck and we gladly help you!

Answer (score 2):

```
import os

for i in range(1, 50):
    env_var = os.environ[f'{i}nl']
    os.system(f"ssh BF-c{env_var} 'hostname; free -h; uname -a;'")
```

Python3.6 >

```
    env_var = os.environ[str(i) + 'nl']
    os.system("ssh BF-c{} 'hostname; free -h; uname -a;'".format(env_var))
```

Comment: python3 test.py 
  File "test.py", line 4
    os.system(f"ssh BF-c{i}nl 'hostname; free -h; uname -a;'")
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: i looks like you removed `'` from end of the 4th file, try copying whole code again.

Comment: Ya, i did, cz it was swearing on that , than on another :D 
File "test.py", line 4
    env_var = os.environ[f'{i}nl']
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Keeps giving Syntax error With or Without '

Comment: @Altitude70007 What is your Python version? We can't see where that syntax error points. But if it points on the `f"`, it may be a version without formatted strings.

Comment: If that's the case, instead of `f"...{i}..."` do `"...{}...".format(i)`

Comment: python3 --version
Python 3.5.2

If that's helps : https://prnt.sc/q6kx5i

Comment: @Altitude70007 f-strings are 3.6+ https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

Comment: python3.7 ssh.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssh.py", line 4, in <module>
    env_var = os.environ[str(i) + 'nl']
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: '1nl'

Comment: It looks like you don't have such environmental variable as `1nl`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [Bash2Py](https://www.swag.uwaterloo.ca/bash2py/index.html).

Also, you can try using the [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/imiell/bash2py/)

Courtesy: [Bash to Python](https://zwischenzugs.com/2016/08/29/bash-to-python-converter/)

So the below code is actually the complete script for conversion.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function

import sys,os

class Bash2Py(object):
  __slots__ = ["val"]
  def __init__(self, value=''):
    self.val = value
  def setValue(self, value=None):
    self.val = value
    return value

def GetVariable(name, local=locals()):
  if name in local:
    return local[name]
  if name in globals():
    return globals()[name]
  return None

def Make(name, local=locals()):
  ret = GetVariable(name, local)
  if ret is None:
    ret = Bash2Py(0)
    globals()[name] = ret
  return ret

def Array(value):
  if isinstance(value, list):
    return value
  if isinstance(value, basestring):
    return value.strip().split(' ')
  return [ value ]

class Expand(object):
  @staticmethod
  def at():
    if (len(sys.argv) < 2):
      return []
    return  sys.argv[1:]
  @staticmethod
  def star(in_quotes):
    if (in_quotes):
      if (len(sys.argv) < 2):
        return ""
      return " ".join(sys.argv[1:])
    return Expand.at()
  @staticmethod

  def hash():
    return  len(sys.argv)-1

if (Expand.hash() < 1 ):
    print("Usage: "+__file__+" file ...")
    exit(1)

print(__file__+" counts the lines of code")

l=Bash2Py(0)

for Make("f").val in Expand.star(0):
    Make("l").setValue(os.popen("wc -l "+str(f.val)+" | sed \"s/^\\([0-9]*\\).*$/\\1/\"").read().rstrip("\n"))
    print(str(f.val)+": "+str(l.val))
```

The guts of the code is in the for loop at the bottom.

bash2py does some safe conversion and wrapping of the bash script into some methods such as ‘Make’, ‘Array’ et al that we can get rid of with a little work.

By replacing:

> Bash2Py(0) with 0 Make(“f”).val with f and Make(“l”) with l etc f.val
>   with f and l.val with l etc

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24772758)

Comment: ok sorry. I add that